# Everyone is installing jQuery library on my site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using Wordpress, it comes with a built-in jQuery library. When I install a plugin, another version gets its way in. I learn to write my own code, the tutorial asks me to install another one!

At the time of this writing, I probably have 4-5 versions of jQuery library installed!

It's going crazy! and I don't think I need that many, I just need the latest one from google CDN for best performance, so I put this line in my php file, but it didn't seem to show up anywhere even after I cleared the cache.

```
function mytheme_jquery_enqueue(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js", false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_jquery_enqueue');
```

How do I fix it and get rid of every other unnecessary version?

Comment: Why don't you just use the latest stable version?

Comment: @Praveen that's exactly what he's trying to do

Comment: jQuery does actually change between versions.  Not saying this is the case, but (at least some of ) the plugins may perhaps require older versions.

Comment: Only use a newer version of jQuery when you absolutely have to. Every time you are forced to use a newer jQuery, test-test-test previously installed plugins against the new version with a view to purging earlier versions. If you can purge, then do so. If you can't, you can't.

Comment: as long as the user doesn't download 5 times jquery it isn't a problem; it's about dependency i'm guessing, now if your site asks 5 times to the browser to download 5 different jquery file you have a problem indeed

Answer (score 2):

First, try to give your hook a lower priority, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_jquery_enqueue', 99999 );
```

This way, it'll be the latest to run, unless some plugin has a priority of `9999999`... [it's a horse race](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/78829/12615)...

---

Then, [Enqueuing jQuery in plug-ins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27575/12615)

> if your code (or the theme's code) is unregistering jQuery and
>   re-registering it from another location (Google), you need to add this
>   somewhere:
>
> ```
> jQuery.noConflict();
> ```
>
> This makes jQuery cooperate with other scripts
>   (i.e. Prototype) that try to define the $ variable globally. WordPress
>   has this line bundled into their version, Google does not.

---

But, better than enqueuing the CDN yourself, it's recommended to use this plugin: [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/). According to a core developer:

> Please do not use that method to include the jQuery script from Google. The above doesn't work and will cause conflicts with other scripts, along with other issues. Use the "Use Google Libraries" plugin instead, if you want to use Google hosted versions of the libraries. This plugin does it right, and is updated often. The method above will only work superficially, it will cause problems down the line. – [Otto Jul 29 '12 at 15:57](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60056/enqueue-jquery-in-wordpress#comment77898_60059)

---

Then, we have the issue that it is really [***not recommended***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45440/12615) to load other jQuery libraries and use the one bundled with WordPress. In which case, you should use `remove_action`, `wp_deregister_script` or `wp_dequeue_script` to prevent all those plugins or theme to load their versions.

> #### [Don’t Dequeue WordPress’ jQuery](http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/)
>
> As a moderator on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), I end up spending a
>   lot of time on the site.  I see lots of great questions, lots of
>   not-so-great questions, and several you’ve-got-to-be-kidding-me
>   questions.  But the question I see the most often frustrates me:
>
> > *How do I remove WordPress’ jQuery and use Google’s CDN version instead?*
>
> I have no trouble saying that, if you’re asking this question, you
>   have no business building a website in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time explaining these steps. I already had "use google libraries" plugin installed. If I understood you correctly, the function 'mytheme_jquery_enqueue' is no longer needed. In addition, I don't need to enqueue jQuery in my plugins. After that, I should deregister 3rd party's jQuery library version. Since dequeuing wordpress' jQuery is not recommended, will my already in-placed " var abc = jQuery.noConflict();" line conflict with wordpress built in "jQuery.noConflict();"? Sorry if I misunderstood you in anyway, English is not my native language... :)

Comment: Well, there's one factor: are you going to release this plugin to the public? In which case, you may not be capable (or responsible) for dequeueing third party plugins. It's up to the user to find well coded and non-conflictive plugins ::: If this is happening in your own controlled environment, then yes, remove your script, prevent other plugins of doing so and let WP do its job. Maybe you'll find yourself in a situation where one plugin won't cooperate and the less hackish solution has to be found.

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestion.